# Android pausing a part of code and waiting for Activity to finish

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hey so i've got this function which speaks and then takes input, then tries to speak again using that input. The problem now is it does all the speaking and doesnt wait for the input

```
public void fun(){
  speakOut("what is your name");
  startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
  speakout("how old are you");

}
```

my program is a bit like the above example. When i run it, it only asks the second question, then runs the activity(in my case its a voice RECOGNIZE_SPEECH intent. 
So what i want is for the code to wait will the activity is finished before carrying on. Or have i got something wrong?

edit:

okay i guess i tried to simplify my question too much =P
i actually have more than 1 question to ask after the activity. I'm planning on looping through them so its something like :

```
for(int i=0;i<listOfQuestions.size;i++){
    speakOut(listOfQuestions.get(i));
    startActivityForResults(intent,2);
}
```

that is why i cannot ask the questions in onActivityResult(). Unless, thats a way i can for what i'm doing

Comment: okay i guess i tried to simplify my question too much =P
i actually have more than 1 question to ask after the activity. I'm planning on looping through them so its something like :

    for(int i=0;i<listOfQuestions.size;i++){
        speakOut(listOfQuestions.get(i));
        startActivityForResults(intent,2);
    }

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) that explains how to use onActivityResult() to be notified when an Activity you have started using startActivityForResult() ends.

Comment: so are you suggesting that i place my second speakout in the onActivityResult()?
i wish i could do that, but i have more in that function that i have to do and i would need to pass all my data into the onActivityResult.

Comment: Yes, you can do a lot of stuff in the onActivityResult(). And if you have too much data to pass through the resulting Intent you could save that data in the second activity (for example in Shared Preferences) and read it in the onActivityResult() of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Activity start as like a seperate program (think like a thread started by that command). Since after start your speakout function called and it's processed quickly before your intent loaded. But actually intent started the process before speakout call. ıf you want speakout to be called after intent call it in the

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
               do_something_with_data();
               speakout("how old are you");
          }
    }
}
```

Also read [Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) document.

Comment: you can't do it that way. It will do the same thing after each activy result. you should change your request code after each call to seperate calls and that way you change your onActivityResult method and add;    `code`else if(requestCode == SECOND_QUESTION_CODE) etc.